# How Can I Install Python Module For Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pybluez

Can anyone help me install the pyBluez module for Python 2.7.10?
Whenever I try to install it I get this error:

```
    C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pyBluez
    Collecting pyBluez 
      Using cached pyBluez-0.22.zip
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Could not find the Windows SDK

        -----------------------------------
     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\super\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ubeyw1\pyBluez
```

Comment: Your title and the body of your question clash. Do you want to install the module for 3.5 or 2.7.10?

Comment: I Want To Install It On 2.7.10

Comment: Try installing the Windows SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: it answers you everytime you try to install it ... it requires windows SDK ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Python 2.7.10 on Windows...

I think you could just download the .exe from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBluez

You just need to download the **MS-Windows Installer** for **your version of Python**.

Hope that helped.